# How to save Spark Java Dstream RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

[Spark Scala API DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)  provides a method `saveAsTextFiles` to store the Dstream RDD on HDFS.

But corresponding method is not available in [Spark Java API's DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStream.html)

How to store DStream RDD in HDFS using Spark Java API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time` parameter can be used to prefix/postfix the actual path.

```
myrdd.foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>, Time, Void>() {
    public Void call(JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> rdd) {
                        rdd.saveAsTextFile(path + "-" + time.toString().split(" ")[0]);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dstream's foreach mathod, you can first get all RDDs from Dstream and then save these rdds using saveAsTextFile method.

Here is the sample code

```
sortedCounts.foreach(new Function<JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>, Void>() {
                    public Void call(JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> rdd) {
                        rdd.saveAsTextFile(path);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Above code replaces the output path for each streaming interval.. (data overrides)

Comment: you can add timestamp with your output path string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dstream()` method to convert JavaDStream to DStream. For example..

```
lines.dstream().saveAsObjectFiles("pre", "suf")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaDStream object is `dstream` and the directory path is `path` you can save it as

```
 dstream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
                rdd.saveAsTextFile(path);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

use forEachRDD API of JavaDStream class.